# How does one find a minimal primary decomposition?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

What exactly does it mean for a primary decomposition to be "minimal" and is the a general method to obtain such decompositions?
I've tried looking at some examples but they all give very little explanation...
If its of relevance I'm working in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of computing primary decompositions -- that's a little harder! At least over Noetherian rings, there's a fairly nice (if slow) method to compute a primary decomposition of an ideal $I$. Check out Irena Swanson's notes on primary decompositions (pages 6-8 walk you through the computation) to see a constructive approach (and a sample computation over ${\mathbb C}[x,y]$):

http://people.reed.edu/~iswanson/primdec.pdf

Comment: the link you posted is now dead